# finding non duplicate integer from give array with odd number of items

Tags: java, arrays

Trying to figure the error with this code. This works for small samples but fails for huge numbers (I don't have a large sample in my hand though).

The solution worked for the following tests.

```
private static final int[] A = {9,3,9,3,9,7,9};
private static final int[] A2 = {9,3,9};
private static final int[] A3 = {9,3,9,3,9,7,7,2,2,11,9};

@Test
public void test(){
    OddOccurance oddOccurance =new OddOccurance();
    int odd=oddOccurance.solution(A);
    assertEquals(7,odd);
}


@Test
public void test2(){
    OddOccurance oddOccurance =new OddOccurance();
    int odd=oddOccurance.solution(A2);
    assertEquals(3,odd);
}


@Test
public void test3(){
    OddOccurance oddOccurance =new OddOccurance();
    int odd=oddOccurance.solution(A3);
    assertEquals(11,odd);
}
```

when an array is given with an odd number of integers (except one integer other integers can be repeated). The solution is to find the non-repeating integer. Any other better ideas (Time and space optimized) to implement this as well, welcome.

```
  public int solution(int[] A) {
    // write your code in Java SE 8
    Map<Integer, List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();
    int value = 0;
    //iterate throught the list and for each array value( key in the map)
    // set how often it appears as the value of the map
    for (int key : A) {

        if (map.containsKey(key)) {
            map.get(key).add(value);

        } else {
            List<Integer> valueList = new ArrayList<>();
            valueList.add(value);
            map.put(key, valueList);
        }

    }

    Set<Map.Entry<Integer, List<Integer>>> entrySet = map.entrySet();
    //   en
    for (Map.Entry<Integer, List<Integer>> entry : entrySet) {
        if (entry.getValue().size() == 1) {
            return entry.getKey();
        }
    }

    return 0;

}
```

**Update**
Looking at failed outputs
WRONG ANSWER,  got 0 expected 42
WRONG ANSWER,  got 0 expected 700

It seems it didn't even go to the for loop but just return 0

Comment: Can you please clarify what `fails` and `huge` means?

Comment: when the size of the array is n= 100,003

Comment: But what do you mean by "fails"? It seems fine to me. Does it take to long? A simple way to optimize is to store count instead of list (so use `HashMap<Integer, Integer>`).

Comment: I would use a `BitSet` - flip each bit (position == number) for each occurrence. At the end a set bit would indicate odd occurrence (A see no need to save a `List` in the map... )

Comment: Yes, it failed. I submitted this codility.com got that it fails for some inputs. Yes, your idea is better instead of List just Integers works here.

Comment: BTW your error probably is that you are not considering (all) odd occurrences, but only **single** ones (`...size() == 1`) IMO, have not really checked/debugged the code (try `{ 1, 9, 1, 9, 1}`

Comment: There is only one odd occurrence and it needs to be retrun in the method @Carlos

Comment: one **odd**  is not the same as a **single** one ; `== 1` is not testing for odd, just for single (`3 ` is odd but not `== 1`)

Comment: all the test cases i included here passe. It coveres your scencario.

Comment: not true, all your test cases only have a **single** occurrence, none have an **odd** one that is not single. After your edit, I wouldn't be surprised that this code is throwing an (ignored) Exception....[to be clear when I say single, I mean the number only occurs once]

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks for not giving up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a standard problem, if the actual statement is the following:

> each number except one appears even number of times; the remaining number appears once.

The solution is to take `xor` of all numbers. Since every repeating number occures even number of times, it will cancel itself. The reason is that `xor` is commutative:

```
a xor b xor c = a xor c xor b = c xor b xor a = etc.
```

For example, in case of `1, 2, 3, 1, 2`

```
1 xor 2 xor 3 xor 1 xor 2 =
(1 xor 1) xor (2 xor 2) xor 3 =
0 xor 0 xor 3 =
3
```

Comment: Can you please explain a little bit more or give a link to an example? what do you mean by it will cancel itself when the occurrence is even number.

Comment: I understand XOR will work here but what is the problem with using Map to solve this. Looking at the code, if (entry.getValue().size() == 1) {
            return entry.getKey();
        } should do the job here.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that your numbers are actually integers? Not, say, longs?

Comment: It is guaranteed. They are integers array "A is an integer within the range [1..1,000,000,000] "

Comment: Thanks for the help this is most simplest solution

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to create a new array containing the frequency of each value. You could start by looping through your initial array to calculate the maximum value in it.

For example, the array `{9,3,9,3,9,7,7,2,2,11,9}` would have a maximum value of 11. With this information, create a new array that can store the frequency of every possible value in your initial array. Then, assuming there is only one integer that repeats once, return the index of the new array that has a frequency of 1. This method should run in `O(n)` where n is the size of the input array.

Here's an implementation:

```
public int solution(int[] inp)
{
    int max = inp[0];

    for(int i = 1; i < inp.length; i++)
    {
        if(inp[i] > max)
            max = inp[i];
    }

    int[] histogram = new int[max + 1]; //We add 1 so we have an index for our max value

    for(int i = 0; i < inp.length; i++)
        histogram[inp[i]]++; //Update the frequency

    for(int i = 0; i < histogram.length; i++)
    {
        if(histogram[i] == 1)
            return i;
    }

    return -1; //Hopefully this doesn't happen
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks max[inp[i]]++; should be replaced from histogram. I am still trying to understand why my solution failed.

Comment: @newday Yup! Good looks.

Comment: The problem was with my code it will fail for this kind of array. I have messed up with single and odd meaning. Therefore, it was faling for this kind of array A3 = {9,3,9,3,9,7,7,2,2,2,11,11,9}

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to know why yours failed without the actual error message.  Regardless, as your array input gets very large, your internal data structure grows accordingly, but doesn't need to.  Instead an array of `Integer` as the value, we can just use one `Integer`:

```
public int solution(int[] a) {

    Integer ONE = 1;

    Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

    for (int key : a) {
        Integer value = (map.containsKey(key)) ? map.get(key) + ONE : ONE;

        map.put(key, value);
    }

    for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        if (entry.getValue().equals(ONE)) {
            return entry.getKey();
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
```

I'm assuming the odd array length requirement is to avoid an array of length of two, where the items would both be unduplicated or duplicated.

Since we don't need the actual total, we can simplify this further and just consider *parity*.  Here's a rework that does and uses the evolving new rules of this question, looking for the odd man out:

```
public int solution(int[] a) {

    Map<Integer, Boolean> odd = new HashMap<>();

    for (int key : a) {
        odd.put(key, (odd.containsKey(key)) ? ! odd.get(key) : Boolean.TRUE);
    }

    for (Map.Entry<Integer, Boolean> entry : odd.entrySet()) {
        if (entry.getValue()) {
            return entry.getKey();
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Returns zero on failure as we now know:

> A is an integer within the range [1..1,000,000,000]